# match only number combinations with a dot at the end with regex

Tags: regex

I need to match only section numbers in text with a dot at the end. For example, having a string:

```
'A.8.    8.4.2.4.1.2.    9.1.    9.    10.0.1.1.    9     0.1     100.     100.5.    A.500'
```

What I want to match: `[A.8., 8.4.2.4.1.2., 9.1., 9., 10.0.1.1., 100., 100.5.]`

What I have matched: `[A.8., 8.4.2.4.1.2., 9.1., 10.0.1.1., 100.5.]`

My regex is `(?:\d+|A)\.[\d+\.]*\.`

Those numbers, without the dot at the end are not matched, which is correct. However, singular numbers with a dot should be matched but are not (such as '9.' and '100.')

How can I update my regex to make it work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok, that seems to work, But if I am using it inside the positive lookahead, then it is not working. See https://regex101.com/r/eKB9gK/1

Comment: You oversimplified the problem. Please update the question with *exact*, real-life issue description. Also, please provide the exact code to repro the issue since whitespace is not easy to deal with in online regex testing tools. Providing a test case will greatly speed up solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```js
\b(?:\d+|A)(?:\.\d+)*\.\B
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mAaSqL/2).

If the matches are whitespace-separated you can also use (granted the regex engine supports lookbehinds):

```js
(?<!\S)(?:\d+|A)(?:\.\d+)*\.(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mAaSqL/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary (start of string or a non-word char should immediately precede the next digit or `A`)
- `(?:\d+|A)` - one or more digits, or an `A`
- `(?:\.\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a dot and then one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\B` - a position other than a word boundary (end of string or a non-word char should follow immediately)

The `(?<!\S)` / `(?!\S)` require a whitespace or start/end of string positions on both ends of the match.

Comment: I am not sure how to use it inside the positive lookahead then. This is my demo: https://regex101.com/r/eKB9gK/1. When I added your regex, then nothing was matched...

Comment: And this is the demo with your regex: https://regex101.com/r/eKB9gK/2

Comment: @skaistt You have a literal two char combination ``\n`` in the regex101 fiddle. Are you sure you did not want to use a simple LF char? Try `^\h*(?=(?:\d+|A)(?:\.\d+)*\.(?!\S))`, see https://regex101.com/r/eKB9gK/3